# how do I trace through a recursion to reverse a linked list?

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

I have some recursive code that reverses linked lists:

#We are dealing with ListNodes.

```
def reverseList(head):
    
    if not head or not head.next:
        return head
    second = head.next
    reverse = reverseList(second)
    second.next = head
    head.next = None

    return reverse
```

I am struggling to follow the code on paper, here is what I understand for say `input 1->2->3->4`:

```
head = 1 
second = head.next = 2 
reverse = reverseList(second=2) 
second = 3 
reverse = reverseList(second=3) 
second = 4
reverse = reverseList(second=4) 

since head.next = None, return head (=4) 

second.next(=None) = 4
... and I am so confused.
```

Am I tracing through the recursion correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To represent the nodes as mere numbers will not help much to understand the algorithm. It is essential that `head`, `second` and `reverse` are node references, and that each recursive call of the function, has its own, distinct set of variables -- even though their names are the same as in another call.

To get better insight, imagine a numeric suffix to each variable, in order to differentiate them according to the execution context they are defined in. So the top level call will have `head1`, `second1`, `reverse1`, and the first recursive call will have its own `head2`, `second2`, `reverse2`, ...etc.

Let's visualise the list at the moment `second` has been initialised:

```
     head1            second1
      ↓                ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
    │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next:None │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

Now the recursive call is made, passing it the reference to the second node. In the recursive execution context, this reference is named `head`, and we also get a new `second` reference:

```
                      head2            second2
                       ↓                ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
    │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next:None │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

A similar set of variables gets assigned in the next recursive execution context:

```
                                       head3            second3
                                        ↓                ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
    │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next:None │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

The deepest recursive call will have its `head` referencing the last node:

```
                                                        head4
                                                         ↓  
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
    │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next:None │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

This deepest call returns `head`. The caller (which has its own set of variables), assigns that return value to `reverse`

```
                                                        reverse3 = head4
                                       head3            second3
                                        ↓                ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
    │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next:None │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

Then `second.next = head` and `head.next = None` get executed:

```
                                                        reverse3
                                       head3            second3
                                        ↓                ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
    │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next: None│ ←——————— :next │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

This call comes to an end, and returns `reverse` to the caller. The caller has its own variables, and assigns the returned reference to their `reverse` variable:

```
                      head2            second2          reverse2 = reverse3 
                       ↓                ↓                ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
    │ next: ———————→ │ next: ———————→ │ next: None│ ←——————— :next │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

Then `second.next = head` and `head.next = None` get executed:

```
                      head2            second2          reverse2
                       ↓                ↓                ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
    │ next: ———————→ │ next: None│ ←——————— :next │ ←——————— :next │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

This call comes to an end, and returns `reverse` to the caller. The caller has its own variables, and assigns the returned reference to their `reverse` variable:

```
     head1            second1                           reverse1 = reverse2 
      ↓                ↓                                 ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
    │ next: ———————→ │ next: None│ ←——————— :next │ ←——————— :next │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

Then `second.next = head` and `head.next = None` get executed:

```
     head1            second1                           reverse1 
      ↓                ↓                                 ↓
    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
    │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │    │ value: 4  │
    │ next: None│ ←——————— :next │ ←——————— :next │ ←——————— :next │
    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘
```

This call comes to an end, and returns `reverse` to the caller. This is indeed the new head of the completely reversed list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation Trincot. Two questions if I may- firstly, when you mentioned "This deepest call returns head. The caller (which has its own set of variables), assigns that return value to reverse" - I understand the first part, but what do you mean the The caller assigns that return value to reverse? As I don't see this in the code or understand it for that matter.

Comment: Secondly, why does reverse stay on the last node?

Comment: The caller assigns the return value to `reverse` here: `reverse = reverseList(second)`. So the `reverseList` call just returned its own `head` reference, and the caller of `reverseList` takes that reference and assigns it to `reverse`.

Comment: The reason why `reverse` stays on the last node: First of all, realise that each `reverse` variable is local & distinct to each execution of the function. But yes, it is logical that it has to be like that. The new head of the reversed list is the last node, and this is true at every step. And from the code you can also see that there is `return reverse`, which means that the caller gets the reference from the deeper recursion, and then returns the same reference, ...and so on.

Comment: Thanks Trincot, that makes perfect sense now. One last thing- for the code above, instead of doing "reverse = self.reverseList(second)" ; could we replaced this with "return self.reverseList(second), and at the end not have "return reverse" of course, and something else?

Comment: No, that is not possible, because *after* the rest of the list has been reversed (through the recursive call), the `head` node needs to be linked to the reversed list as its new tail.  This can only be done after the recursive call, so you cannot return yet before `head` has been added as tail to that partial result. Only when that has been done you can return.

Comment: Hi trincot, I am going over the above code again, and one question if I may. When we hit the recursive call "reverse = reverseList(second)"; am I right in understanding that we DO NOT move onto the next line "second.next = head" until we hit the base case?

Comment: My understanding is that in a function we will continue running each line of code until we hit a 'return' statement. Or is this not the case with the recursive call?

Comment: When a recursive call is made, the execution context of the caller is "frozen" and put on a call stack. The nested execution will do its job, and the same will happen if it also makes the recursive call. So you get a stack of callers who are all pending. The base case will return a value and the last caller will be popped from the stack and will continue with its next statement, i.e. `second.next = head`. When it returns, then the next caller will be popped from the stack, and it will execute its own `second.next = head`, ...etc. Remember that a `return` will return to the  *last* caller only.